# Alternative to Friedman's?

Tags: friedman-test

I have ordinal data (from Likert scores) that are not normally distributed and is paired,there are more than 3 tests over time. There will be something in the region of 150 people evaluated.
How do I choose between Friedmans and Wilcoxon signed-rank tests? Is there any other and if so what would be the benefits of using it?

Comment: Start from searching `Friedman Wilcoxon` on this site and reading through.